# Astable Multivibrator - Kalafuna is burning, not switching

Tags: oscillator

I am having problems with circuit, that I designed. 
[image: AStable Multivibrator]

R1=R2=R3=R4= 680 ohm; C1=C2 = 20nF; R5=R6 = 7,3kohm
Circuit works only when voltage is about 0,5-0,7V and resistors r5/r6 are not connected.
It "should" oscillate at 50Khz.

** R5=R6 Are calculated for hfe=306 measured.
Designed for 20V -> 680 ohm -> U/R -> 20/680 = 0,0294A. Thats what transistor should turn on. With hfe 306 -> 0,0294/306 -> 0,000096 A. Thats minimal current for turn it ON. So to bypass turning second transistor On when capacitor rise 0,7V - resistor is calculated for 20V -> 20/0,000096 = 208kOhms. 
With resistors connected, there is no switching and i got nice smell from burning resistor R1 when rising voltage to 20V.

Comment: What is the wattage rating of these resistors?

Comment: You realize that  at 20V your R1/R2 are dissipating nearly 600mW when on?

Comment: As a circuit designer I **NEVER** use the measured value of hfe because there is no need, results in too much work and when a transistor needs to be replaced and the new one has a lower hfe, I would have to replace the resistors as well. For the 2n3904 just assume hfe = 100 and design for that. Then the base currents are higher but that doesn't matter. Doing all this hfe stuff made you forget to calculate the power dissipation in the collector resistors as Oldfart rightly remarks.

Comment: Burning resistors are not problem. Its just title.... I am curious about why its not oscilating...

Comment: What is "Kalafuna"?

Comment: And i forgot to say "thanks" for help

Comment: kalafuna = rosin

Comment: Does anyone know why its not oscilating ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R5 and R6 are your problem.

In the standard design for an astable multivibrator [reference 1](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html), [reference 2](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-multivib-a.html) these resistors are not included.

> R5=R6 Are calculated for hfe=306 measured.

This is an indication of the problem. As Bimpelrekkie said in the comments, hfe shouldn't matter. In an astable multivibrator the transistors should be acting as pure switches. When they're on, we wish them to be all-the-way "on" i.e. driven into pure saturation, and when they're off we wish them to be all-the-way "off", i.e. driven into complete cutoff mode. For that reason, hfe should be ignored, because we should always design the circuit to *wildly* exceed the requirements for turn-on and turn-off given a particular hfe value.

If we [simulate your circuit on circuitjs](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+8.281975887399955+50+5+50%0Aw+112+48+208+48+0%0Aw+208+48+288+48+0%0Aw+288+48+384+48+0%0Ar+112+48+112+176+0+680%0Ar+208+48+208+176+0+680%0Ar+288+48+288+176+0+680%0Ar+384+48+384+176+0+680%0Ac+112+176+208+176+0+2e-8+-18.28242950952135%0Ac+384+176+288+176+0+2e-8+-18.28242950952135%0Aw+384+176+384+240+0%0At+336+256+384+256+0+1+0.6145744177073451+0.686372105112924+100%0Aw+208+176+288+256+0%0Aw+288+176+208+256+0%0At+160+256+112+256+0+1+0.6145744177073464+0.6863721051129242+100%0Aw+112+176+112+240+0%0AR+112+48+64+48+0+0+40+20+0+0+0.5%0Ag+112+272+112+304+0%0Ag+384+272+384+304+0%0Ax+159+212+179+215+4+16+C1%0Ax+317+213+337+216+4+16+C2%0Ax+85+260+106+263+4+16+Q1%0Ax+390+259+411+262+4+16+Q2%0A403+192+208+224+240+0+12_256_0_4102_20_0.1_0_2_12_3%0A403+272+208+304+240+0+11_256_0_4102_20_0.4_0_2_11_3%0A403+320+128+352+160+0+8_128_0_4102_20_0.4_0_2_8_3%0A403+144+128+176+160+0+7_128_0_4102_20_0.1_0_2_7_3%0Ar+160+256+208+256+0+7300%0Ar+288+256+336+256+0+7300%0Ao+13+32+6+4099+1.1051191402562348+0.0001+0+2+10+6%0A) it shows the same behavior that you see in your physical circuit... except that it predicts that *both* R1 and R4 should be burning up.

If you delete R5 and R6 (or just set them to a tiny value like 0.1 ohms) then the circuit will begin oscillating... but in a pretty ugly fashion until you increase the values of R2 and R3 (1k worked for me). Tuning to the correct frequency is left as an exercise for the reader -- reference 1 above tells you exactly how to do it. Also make sure to get some higher-wattage resistors, as noted in the comments.